No click can be made on the entire top-right corner of a maximized app in Ubuntu 24.04
I installed a fresh Ubuntu 24.04 installation on a PC.
Now the problem is that the entire top-right corner of any maximized app can not be clicked.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong and how to fix it?

That is weird that mouse clicks cannot be detected in only a portion of the screen.  Is it consistent ie. always happening?

@user628388, yes, it's happening for all programs.

If you have the necessary packages installed for remote access (I use xrdp), would it react the same way remotely?

I have seen remote access suddenly not respond to any mouse activity however, in that case, I terminate the remote session (don't even log out first) then start a new remote session - everything is fine.  -- Even if it's the system console (display), what if you logged the main ID out then logged in with a second ID?

As of Ubuntu 18.04, you generally cannot connect with an ID while that ID is actively being used as the system console.

back. In my case, I discovered that the problem was caused by anydesk, I uninstalled it, restarted my machine and it was solved.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This is correct. I removed AnyDesk and the problem disappeared.

@SaeedNeamati Please mark the answer as accepted.

anydesk seems to have caused it for me too, but theres no problem with anydesk on ubuntu 22.04
